# Divide and Conquer Algorithms Numerical

Tags: algorithm

If a file of size n=1000 takes 10 ms for sorting using randomized quick sort algorithm,then approximately how much time would it take to sort a file of size n=1000000000?(assume that all data are available in the main memory)

Comment: This probably belongs on math.stackexchange since it's a numerical calculation question not about programming or algorithms in any way, except superficially. They should know that the expected running time of quick sort is Theta(n log n), if not then just tell them and they should have no problem helping you.

Comment: Are you using a desktop computer?
One operation inside your quicksort takes about 1 microsecond of time, which is too slow. Perhaps you have issues in your implementation / time measurement, or the sorting takes quadratic time.

Answer (score 2):

If in general the average time (or number of basic operations) for randomized Quicksort is O(n log(n)) and for n=10^3 takes 10ms, means that relation 10 = t 10^3 log(10^3), where t is the time for operations holds. From previous relation you obtain the time your computer spends with one basic operation t=10/(10^3 log(10^3)) ms. Therefore, the time to finish with n=10^9 is t 10^9 log(10^9). Substituting with t=10/(10^3 log(10^3)) you get that your computer needs 10/(10^3 log(10^3)) 10^9 log(10^9) ms, or 10^7 9/3 ms.

is it that what you were looking for?